# Extending expansion of variable dependent on two independent variables including their time derivatives?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, taylor-expansion

The general **Taylor series** expansion of a variable $F$ is:

$$
F = F_0 + \overbrace{\frac{1}{1!}\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} \Delta t}^{\text{Linear}} + \overbrace{\frac{1}{2!}\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial t^2} \Delta t^2}^{\text{Non-Linear}} + \cdots
$$

**$F$** is a vector (hydrodynamic force), which is a function of two components displacement and velocity, $F = f(x,y,\dot{x},\dot{y})$.\
By using Taylor series for the variable $F$ and including the *Non-Linear* part, I got a problem with the *Non-Linear velocity terms*

Here is the expansion:
\begin{align*}
F_x = F_{x0} +&
\overbrace{\underbrace{\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial x} x + 
\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y} y}_{\text{displacement terms}} + \underbrace{\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial \dot{x}} \dot{x} + 
\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial \dot{y}} \dot{y}}_{\text{velocity terms}}}^{\text{Linear}}+ \\[2em]
{}
&\overbrace{\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\biggl[\frac{\partial^2 F_x}{\partial x^2} x^2 +
2 \frac{\partial^2 F_x}{\partial x \partial y}  x  y + 
\frac{\partial^2 F_x}{\partial y^2} y^2\biggr]}_{\text{displacement terms}}+
\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\biggl[  \cdots     \biggr]}_{\text{velocity terms}}}^{\text{Non-Linear}}
\end{align*}
What are the *Non-Linear velocity terms*?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix

Comment: @polfosol - I checked that, but my question is specific on the expansion of the Non-Linear part of the time-dependent of a variable depends on two independent variables, i.e. the velocity terms in Non-Linear part?

Comment: Your confusion is originated from the notation. Just replace $(x,y,\dot{x},\dot{y})$ with $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ to see what I am saying

Comment: For the first and last terms, it's kind of easy, $$\frac{\partial^2 F_x}{2\partial x \partial \dot{x}} 2 x \dot{x}$$ and the same for the *y* part, the hard one is the denominator of the middle term, $$2\frac{\partial^2 F_x}{\partial t \partial x \partial y}(\dot{x}y+x\dot{y})$$, which I'm not sure about it.

Comment: @polfosol - Thanks for your suggestion, I've worked depending on your advice and the problem has been resolved.